# Connecting to two different networks at the same time is not working

Tags: networking, windows-10, routing

I am trying (and failing) to setup the following networking situation:

My PC (which runs Windows 10) is connected via Wi-Fi to a router. It gets all the network settings via DHCP and they look as follows:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : fritz.box
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.37
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.1
```

I have also connected the PC via ethernet to a small 8-port non-managed switch. Also connected to that switch is another PC running Freenas. The system running Freenas has a static IP of 192.168.0.100/24. I have configured my PC to have a static IP of 192.168.0.50/24.

I had hoped that Windows would be able to reach my server just based on the different subnets, but it can't. So I have tried to set the following routes (one by one) in Windows:

```
route -p ADD 192.168.0.100 MASK 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0 IF 12
route -p ADD 192.168.0.100 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 IF 12
route -p ADD 192.168.0.100 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.50 IF 12
```

IF 12 is my ethernet card. Even with these routes I am unable to reach the server.

Now I feel like I have a basic error in my thinking. Or am I just missing something?

By the way, I have no intention to connect the two networks to each other. I just want to be able to access the internet from my normal PC and have a connection to the NAS at the same time.

EDIT (as requested):

Output of ipconfig for wired connection:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.50
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Output of "route print":

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 11...10 fe ed 1e c7 8b ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
 18...10 fe ed 1e c7 8b ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #4
  7...00 ff 42 f2 8d 7f ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
  3...10 fe ed 1e c7 8b ......Realtek RTL8192CU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 12...30 9c 23 7f ec a3 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.178.1  192.168.178.222    306
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0   192.168.178.37  192.168.178.222     51
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.0.50    356
     192.168.0.50  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.50    356
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.50    356
    192.168.178.0    255.255.255.0         On-link   192.168.178.222    306
  192.168.178.222  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.178.222    306
  192.168.178.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.178.222    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link   192.168.178.222    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.0.50    356
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   192.168.178.222    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.0.50    356
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0   192.168.178.37       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.178.1  Default
===========================================================================
```

I have removed all the IPv6 information from the output.

Comment: show us the ipconfig for the wired connection, and  `route print`.

Comment: *I had hoped that Windows would be able to reach my server just based on the different subnets, but it can't.* You must. But can't. Resume: you overset something and damage connection... Check - no settings for NIC except IP/mask is set.

Comment: @FrankThomas I have added the requested information.